# advertising with VAST not working in JWPlayer 6.2

Tags: php, jwplayer, ads

I use this code to load JWPlayer 6.2 player with adspeed ad,  I followed instructions on their website but the ad isn't loading, it's still loading the file only, can you help me load the ad?

```js
jwplayer("sr_player").setup({ <? php

  if (!empty($movFiles['geo'][1]['sd'])) {

    ?>
    sources: [{
      file: "<?=$hd_file?>",
      label: "HD სწრაფი ინტერნეტი"
    }, {
      file: "<?=$lq_file?>",
      label: "SD ნელი ინტერნეტი"
    }], <? php
  } else { ?>
    file: "<?=$hd_file?>", <? php
  } ?>
  'width': '100%',
  'height': '460',
  startparam: "start",
  primary: 'html5',
  aboutlink: "",
  //abouttext:"Team DGT (look in index5.html to change)",
  modes: [],
  advertising: {
    client: 'vast',
    tag: 'http://g.adspeed.net/ad.php?do=vast&aid=235939&vastver=3&cb=1437483866'
  }
});
```

Comment: First step, upgrade to JW Player 6.12.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where you are running please?